# Convert style attribute to ng-style

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I have following style in an angularjs application, which is working fine.
Can this be replaced by ng-style, or its better to stick to the style attribute as I have it now?

```
style="border-bottom:solid {{command.name == 'Delete' ? '1px':'0px'}} lightgray;
                      padding-bottom:{{command.name == 'Delete' ? '10px':'0px'}};
```

The ng-style code that I tried but which didn't work.

```
ng-style="{border-bottom:solid {{command.name == 'Delete' ? '1px':'0px'}} lightgray;
                   padding-bottom:{{command.name == 'Delete' ? '10px':'0px'}}; }"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it takes an object, no need to do {{}} in there:

```
ng-style="{
    borderBottom: 'solid ' + (command.name == 'Delete' ? '1px':'0px') + ' lightgray',
    paddingBottom: (command.name == 'Delete' ? '10px':'0px')
}"
```

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work.  Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ';' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 147 of the expression

Comment: If I did these 2  changes to your code, then it worked:  use parenthesis for the expression after paddingBottom, remove the last semi colon

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to remove the ';'. I fixed the answer

Comment: You need to put command.name == 'Delete' ? '10px':'0px' in parenthesis, else its still giving an error.

Comment: It shouldn't... but if you say so. Edited to include that as well.

Comment: Yes you are right, I could do without the parenthesis for the last expression.